# How to create a method, which can update the caller about its progress of tasks it is performing?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a method which can update(in particular time interval) the user about the progress of tasks it is performing & finally, can return a result true/false or any object.

For eg I have to create a method which encrypts or decrypts a file/directory. So I have to show the progress of encryption/decryption & at the end I have to return true or false value whether file is encrypted/decrypted successfully or not.

I want to create this in Android(Java) & the method should be an independent one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AsyncTask

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

You can even put this in a service running alone even if the app is in background..

Answer (score 0):

you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

in AsyncTask you can do things in `doInBackground`. during the task you can post progress by calling `publishProgress` method which will be catched by `onProgressUpdate` method. also when the task is finished the `onPostExecute` method will be called. So that is what you want.

So all you need to do this something like that

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         // Do your task and during the task calculate the progress and call publishProgress to publish the progress
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         progress received
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         task finihshed
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this & let you know about my status.